# Appending multiple html elements using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Am new to jQuery and wondering if any could advise me on best practise...

I am looking to append a div element to the page, which contains a lot of html and not sure what the best way to achieve this is....or if it is advisable using jquery...

For example, if I wanted to append the following code to the page using jquery, what is the best way.

```
<div id="test">
    <h1>This is the test</h1>
    <p>Hello, just a test</p>
    <a href="www.test.com">Click me</a>
    <a href="www.test.com">Click me again</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25):

If you want to add the HTML as it is, then just use the jQuery append function.
For example:

```
$('body').append('
<div id="test">\
    <h1>This is the test</h1>\
       <p>Hello, just a test</p>\
       <a href="www.test.com">Click me</a>\
       <a href="www.test.com">Click me again</a>\
</div>');
```

Change the selector from body to other DOM element/selector according to your requirement.

Or if you already have the div element with ID "test" in the document, then you can set the content using the html() function like below:

```
$("#test").html('<h1>This is the test</h1>\
       <p>Hello, just a test</p>\
       <a href="www.test.com">Click me</a>\
       <a href="www.test.com">Click me again</a>');
```

Comment: is this a better method than putting the content into an joined array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you referring to slashes used for each line-breaks?

Comment: i mean doing this as an alternative...

var array1 = ['<div id="test">',
              '<h1>This is the test</h1>',
              '<p>Hello, just a test</p>',
              '<a href="www.test.com">Click me</a>',
              '<a href="www.test.com">Click me again</a>',
           '</div>'];

        $(array1.join(''))
            .appendTo('#test');

Comment: I don't know why you'd put them in an array. Anyway, its not any 'better' than your method.Its just a matter of preference, and I prefer the method I wrote above.

Comment: Why do we need to put \ at the end of lines? & is there any way of doing this automatically?

Comment: @studioromeo It's a multiline string literal. You can read more [here](http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings).

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#id_of_div").append($("#id_of_div_that_you_wanna_append").html());
```

Comment: is it best to use a div already in the html, or to use Jquery to create the html on the fly for you to use...eg 

     $('<div id ="test><h1>This is the test</h1></div>).appendTo('body')

Sorry, am trying to make this appear as a code block, but doesnt seem to be working

Comment: You don't need the .html() at the end.

Comment: You need the .html() at the end if you're planning on multiple copies.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#test").append("YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE");
```

Answer (score 0):

With **ES6** (ECMAScript 2015) you can now use the backticks to surround all the HTML even with single or double quotes (useful also to add variables inbetween).

However, since the question seemed to focus on adding the entire block **after** some existing element, perhaps the [`after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) method would be more suitable than the [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) one in this case. This is the difference between them (run the snippet):

```js
let $num = 0;
$('main').append(`
  <article>
    <h2>Appended ${++$num}</h2>
    <p>Using 'single' and "double-quotes" without escaping!</p>
  </article>
  
  <article>
    <h2>Appended ${++$num}</h2>
    <p>Using 'single' and "double-quotes" without escaping!</p>
  </article>
`).after(`
  <footer>
    <h2>Added after main</h2>
    <p><b>${++$num} blocks</b> of multiple elements were added through jQuery</p>
  </footer>
`);
```

```css
article {background: #eee;border:1px solid #000;padding:1rem}
main {background: #ccc;padding:1rem}
body {background: #aaa;padding:1rem}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>Main section</h1>
  <article>
    <h2>jQuery</h2>
    <p>Adding multiple elements...</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

### *Note*

You can also use the equivalent [`insertAfter`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) and [`appendTo`](https://api.jquery.com/?s=append) if you prefer this alternative syntax: `$('<p>my html</p>').insertAfter('main')`

The jQuery object containing the HTML blocks to add goes first and you only need to reference the string in the method's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are following methods:

1. Use "+" to join HTML code pieces.
2. Use "\" to escape.
3. Use "`" (back-tick, [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)), do not need any extra operations.
   This method is supported from ES2015/ES6 ([Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).
4. Add a hidden `tag` containing the same HTML code you need, e.g. `<p id="foo" style="display:none;">`, then use`.append($('#foo').html());`.

   Now post some use scenarios to the `first three methods` metioned above (just run them in the console of `Chrome` browser.):
   [image]

We can see their differences clearly.